# pdf to searchable ps

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, postscript, poppler

I know people have asked similar question but couldn't find an answer to this. I have a pdf file that was produced using pdflatex. It is searchable (you can press ctrl+f and search for words inside) and it uses hyperref for the citations. I want to make a ps file out of it.

I tried pdf2ps from gs and pdftops from the poppler package. Both make the document like it is a picture. You cannot search anything inside and also the hyperrefs don't work.

Any way I can make a ps file but at least keep it searchable?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to 'search inside' a PostScript file ? A PostScript file is for printing.

What do you mean by 'hyperrefs don't work', what do you expect them to do ?

Comment: The pdf is a paper to be submitted to a journal. Which journal accepts only postscript files and needs to be searchable. Usually, I use latex and I produce the ps directly which is searchable. This time, due to some collaborators, the document was made in pdf with pdflatex so it needs to be transformed to ps to be submitted.

Comment: The journal is asking for 'searcahble' PostScript ? If so they are not being reasonable. To be frank, PostScript is not 'searchable', it was never intended to be, has no requirement to be, and usually is absolutely not 'searchable' in any meaningful sense. If you want a 'searchable' format which can be printed, use PDF. You can try Ghostscript's ps2write device, but to avoid the entire page being compressed (*NOT* a picture, just a compressed data stream) you will need to specify -dCompressPages=false on the Ghostscript command line.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this tool: [renderpdf](https://www.cairographics.org/cookbook/renderpdf/)

I don't know about citations, but it makes searchable postscript files